# Shopping for an oven on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Albeit this maybe a featured question isn't this particular question off topic?

[What oven should I buy, which is appropriate for baking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24874/what-oven-should-i-buy-which-is-appropriate-for-baking)

From my understanding, i thought that [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are off topic if you're trying to poll or ask for an opinion.

Examples of on topic shopping questions:

- What qualities should i look for in a convection oven?
- How do i select the best watermelon for my next meal?

This particular question at the current moment seems like the OP is asking for an opinion (correct me if i'm wrong):

> If you would compare them, which one to choose? The price is around
>   the same and within my budget.

Answer (score 1):

See the comment I left under the question you mention:

> Note that your question was on the verge all the time, because we don't do shopping recommendations here. It is fine to ask what criteria to use when choosing, but not to ask people "which model should I get", see blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping. I removed the flags the question picked, but maybe you can clean it up so it asks more clearly about the criteria.

It is mentioned in the blog post you linked too: questions about criteria for choosing a tool are ontopic. Questions about "which brand should I buy" are offtopic. The question you mention mixes these a bit, but because it hasn't turned into a flame war à la "My oven is better than everybody else's", I decided to leave it open and hope that people will start listing criteria and/or the OP will edit to make it clear that it isn't about brand recommendations.

Comment: IMHO ATM, I don't feel that the question is going anywhere considering it needs heavy editing. It took me several minutes to figure out what this person wanted or to determine what the question the OP had.

Comment: @chrisjlee, it may have some quality problems but that doesn't make it off-topic. Aside from the poorly-worded title, most of the question is more along the lines of "how should I choose" as opposed to "what should I buy", which is fine. The question even very specifically states the problem that needs to be solved by the new oven.

Comment: Also, it should be noted, that the Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping is actually fairly specific to Superuser. E.g., oven technology doesn't "[move] so rapidly that the best shopping recommendations will be utterly obsolete within a year!"